# Are a.e. derivatives of continuous $VBG_*$ functions Denjoy–Perron integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, decomposition-theorem

I would like to ask a question pertaining to the Denjoy–Perron (Henstock–Kurzweil) theory of integration. It is simple enough that I have entertained the idea that perhaps an answer is known, but I have not stumbled upon a definite answer in the literature yet.

I will ask the question using the terminology of $VBG_*$ and $ACG_*$ functions, but my interest lies in the more modern language of variational measures. If $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ coincides a.e. with the derivative of a continuous $VBG_*$ function $F:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, is it then the case that $f$ is Denjoy–Perron integrable? It may be that integration does not allow us to construct $F$ from $f$, but this is not a problem for I am merely interested in the integrability of $f$.

Let $E$ denote the subset of $[a, b]$ on which $F$ admits an infinite derivative. If $\mu(F(E)) = 0$ then standard results allow us to conclude that $f$ is Denjoy–Perron integrable. The case $\mu(F(E))>0$ appears to be a bit more difficult, at least for me. To my understanding $F$ is quite well-behaved on the set of points at which it does not admit a derivative (finite or infinite), so much of my attention has gone towards the set $E$.

If this is true then we would end up with a singular decomposition theorem based on $VBG_*$ and $ACG_*$ functions. At some point or another I'm sure that Denjoy, Luzin, Saks etc would have asked (and perhaps resolved) this question. I would greatly appreciate some help.

**Edit:** I recently posed this question to Valentin Skvortsov in an email. Initially he too entertained the idea that perhaps my conjecture is correct. However, today he told me that one of his former students (and now assistant professor) Piotr Sworowski disproved my conjecture. I will update this post with further details at a later time. I must first study some counterexamples myself.